# Determining value of preprocessor token

Tags: c++, macros

How can I tell what the value of the `__GNUC__` definition is on my C++ compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all the GCC predefined macros with this:

```
g++ -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

A quick grep will get you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use `gcc`'s "preprocess only" mode (`-E`) (and give it input via STDIN rather than a file for convenience):

```
[tomalak@renee ~]$ echo "__GNUC__" | g++ -E -
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
4
```

I'm not sure what the first four lines of output are, but the final line is what you're looking for.

Comment: The # lines are line markers. They tell us where the input came from (standard input in your case). Adding "-P" to the command line disables them

Answer (score 1):

This works for any macro:

```
echo "int main() {}" | gcc -xc++ -ggdb3 -
readelf --debug-dump=macro a.out | grep MACRO_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR
```

or

```
dwarfdump -m a.out | grep MACRO_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR
```

Comment: Well, the actually code is just the second line. If you want to look for predefined macros, there are better ways. But if you want a macro value in a binary, this is the way to go.

Comment: Hang on.. how does this work? Why does the macro definition still exist in the binary? Purely because of `-ggdb3`?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Yes. Or more precisely due to DWARF (however you turn it on).